# How to get data from elastic search, if new data came then update it, and again inject it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have nearly 200 000 lines of tuples in my Pandas Dataframe. I injected that data into elastic search. Now, when I run the program It should check whether the present data already there in elastic search if not present insert into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to not worry about it and just load everything into Elasticsearch. As long as your `_id`s are consistent the existing documents will be overwritten instead of duplicated. So just be sure to specify an `_id` for each document and you are fine, the `bulk` helpers in the `elasticsearch-py` client all support you setting an `_id` value for each document alredy.